# Tkinter theme Equilux Vertical Slider issue

Tags: tkinter, ttk

When I applied the theme style from ttkthemes called "equilux' my vertical slider looks strange.  The horizontal looks fine. If anyone has seen a solution to this I would like to know.  I have looked and not found any.  I also looked at the code for this and didn't see anything out of the ordinary. [image]

```
from tkinter import *
import tkinter.ttk as ttk
from  ttkthemes import ThemedStyle
root =Tk()
root.geometry("800x600")
root.configure(background = 'grey14')
root.resizable(1,1)
style =ThemedStyle(root)
style.set_theme('equilux') 


# Create Horizontal Slider
Horz_slider =ttk.Scale(root, from_=0, to=100, orient=HORIZONTAL, value=0, length=360)
Horz_slider.grid(row=2,column = 1)

# Create Vertical Slider
Vert_slider = ttk.Scale(root, from_=0, to=100, orient=VERTICAL, value=0, length=360)
Vert_slider.grid(row=2,column = 3)


root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Just to clarify, are you saying that if you use some other theme you don't get the same behavior?

Comment: No just this theme, equilux.  I have checked out the code for the theme itself and looked at the pictures it is using but I can't find the problem.

Comment: Bryan Oakley, have you tried this out to see what you think maybe wrong?

Comment: Well after a week I finally figured it out.  The pic files that were used was incorrect.  They had a knob for the length and it just stretched ot out.  Found the correct one and changed the name of the file to through-vert-active.